# Running `pip` gives 'command not found' after successful Python homebrew install

Tags: bash, terminal, python, homebrew, pip

To preface, I am very bad with the terminal, please be patient with me.

when I run `pip` I get:
    `zsh: command not found: pip`

I have installed Python 2.7.11 with brew, which should allow pip to work
When I run `echo $PATH` I get

```
/usr/local/sbin /Users/Nicolas/.composer/vendor/bin /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin
```

I notice that /usr/local/bin/ is in there, which I understand is where brew executables are linked to

when I run `which -a python` I get

```
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

So-- two Python installs. I'm guessing one is the native OSX one and one is the homebrew install.
When I run `which python` I get

```
/usr/local/bin/python
```

So this is the python that gets run when python is called, right?
When I run `ls -l $(which python)` I get

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 Nicolas  admin  34 Feb  3 14:26 /usr/local/bin/python -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.11/bin/python
```

I think this is where the problem is; I notice that there is a /python/2.7.11/libexec folder...

I have also tried `brew unlink python && brew link python` to no avail

when I try `brew list python | grep pip` I get a very long list of results

This is probably the most important one

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/libexec/pip/pip/__init__.py
```

I don't know how to proceed from here... I think it has to do with pip being in `python/2.7.11/libexec` instead of `python/2.7.11/bin`

When I run `which -a pip` I get `pip not found`

Someone from SO tried to help me but it was not successful. I believe that pip may be installed somewhere, and working, but simply invoking `pip` does nothing.

The person told me to remove `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.0.2-py2.7.egg` which I did successfully with `rmdir` but I'm not sure where it leaves me now

I am not familiar with most of this stuff; my understanding of terminal is very limited. I am not sure how to proceed from here. Any and all help is appreciated, thanks.